# Sourceforge: "... does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, repository, push, sourceforge

I have started a project on Sourceforge, mainly for trying out how it works. Here is a link to the project: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tachikomawall/ But pushing the source code to the project doesn't work for me. I'm trying to use GIT for the purpose. Here is the error it returns:

```
[18:09] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git push origin master
matachi@tachikomawall.git.sourceforge.net's password: 
fatal: '/gitroot/tachikomawall/code' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Here are some lines that I typed in the terminal before (I don't think I forgot anything):

```
[17:57] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git init
[17:57] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git config user.name "MaTachi"
[17:58] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git config user.email "matachi@users.sourceforge.net"
[17:58] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git add .
[17:58] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git commit
[master (root-commit) 637d52b] first commit
 5 files changed, 91 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README
 create mode 100644 images/bg.png
 create mode 100644 include/style.css
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 index.php
[18:08] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git remote add origin ssh://matachi@tachikomawall.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/tachikomawall/code
[18:08] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git config branch.master.remote origin
[18:09] matachi ~/Projects/htdocs/Tachikoma-Wall $ git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

I guess according to the error message that I haven't written the correct repository name. As you may understand, I haven't used GIT before and doesn't really understand how it works yet.

Comment: i think the url should be ssh://matachi@tachikomawall.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/tachikomawall/tachikomawall. you should find the url on the page https://sourceforge.net/projects/tachikomawall/develop

Comment: Didn't work. :( "fatal: '/gitroot/tachikomawall/tachikomaw‌​all' does not appear to be a git repository"

Comment: is that the url you find on https://sourceforge.net/projects/tachikomawall/develop? And have you actually enabled git-support for your project? I don't think it's on by default

Comment: Apparently it's enabled by default, but the guide on their own site is wrong. https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git I tried to do "git remote add origin ssh://USERNAME@PROJECTNAME.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/PROJECTNAME/REPONAME" but it should be "git remote add origin ssh://matachi@git.code.sf.net/p/tachikomawall/code". Anyway, thanks knittl!

Comment: hm. outdated documentation? That's why I posted the link to the development page, which contains the correct url ;)

Comment: I assumed that the guide was correct. ^^ But I filled a form on Sourceforge about this, so hopefully the guide gets updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and saw the comments on your question.
Just for clarification's sake:

The guide on https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/wiki/Git is **wrong**.

*Don't* clone/pull/push from:

> ssh://USERNAME@PROJECTNAME.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/PROJECTNAME/REPONAME

Instead, do it from:

> ssh://USERNAME@git.code.sf.net/p/PROJECTNAME/REPONAME

Comment: Why they give the wrong URL and just leave it there is still baffling thousands of people, but it's true. :)